# Avoid returning multiple outputs same as the records count for member method in Oracle

Tags: oracle, object, methods, oracle11g, oracle12c

I implemented a member method to return the number of records in the db.

```
CREATE or replace TYPE BODY student_t AS    
MEMBER FUNCTION getRecordCount RETURN NUMBER IS
recordCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select count(*) into recordCount
    from student s;
    return recordCount;
END;END;/
```

But it will generate the correct output multiple times which is similar to total number of records. So how to modify above member function to display the result 
only one time?

I am executing it as follows;

```
select s.getRecordCount() from student s/
```

Comment: Can you post how are you executing it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execution should include a DISTINCT clause:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT S.GETRECORDCOUNT() FROM STUDENT S;
```

This is because when you created a table of your object type, for each row in the table, the member function is called, hence you get multiple instances(since multiple rows in your table).

See demo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE student_t AS OBJECT
(
    col1 varchar2(100),
     MEMBER FUNCTION getRecordCount
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY student_t
AS
   MEMBER FUNCTION getRecordCount
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      recordCount   NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      SELECT  COUNT (*)
        INTO recordCount
        FROM student s ;        

      RETURN recordCount;
   END;
END;
/

--table created of Object type
CREATE TABLE STUDENT OF STUDENT_T
```

EDIT:
   Table is populated:

```
SQL> Select * from STUDENT;

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
XXX
YY
XXX
```

Execution:

```
SQL> SELECT  DISTINCT S.GETRECORDCOUNT() FROM STUDENT S;

S.GETRECORDCOUNT()
------------------
                 3
```

Comment: I don't like this answer, because it's a dirty workaround for a wrong model. A student has no record count, so the class should simply not contain such method. Apart from this: when thinking in objects, one should not think in records. So a student may have a method `get_subject_count` to say how many subjects the student studies for instance, but certainly not a method `GETRECORDCOUNT` to say how many *records* the student has (unless it's records gained in competitions).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I appreciate your downvote but i just replied the question asked. You can downvote the question rather downvoting the answer. Also you can post your thoughts as that would give you more satisfaction. Also , i guess the question is not addressing a real world scenario rather it looks like a learning exercise

Comment: No, I wouldn't downvote the question. The question is clear and easy to understand. The OP creates an object with a method and is surprised to get the method's results multiplied. The reason is a misunderstanding on their part about how such object should work. Which can be explained in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you wanna try to produce is this :

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION getRecordCount RETURN NUMBER IS
    recordCount NUMBER;
BEGIN
    select count(1) into recordCount from student s;
   return recordCount;
END;
/

SQL> select getRecordCount from dual;
```

ain't that?

Comment: count(1) also gave the similar result. Actually I tried using member methods not functions.

Comment: @A.Wen no, i've meant to use `function` instead of `type`. ( count(1) is for only performance reasons. )

Comment: Function also produced the same output.

Comment: @A.Wen: What Barbaros Özhan is saying is if you don't make this an object's member function, you would not select it from the students table, but from dual and would hence just get one result row only. But well, I guess you *do* want this to be an object's member function, so this answer doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistakenly misusing the concept of objects.

You create an object to represent a **student**. A member function that gets data should hence give you information about the student.

But you are asking the object for information about the **class** or **university** or whatever this is, namely how many students it contains.

A student has no count you can retrieve. A university etc. does. So you need another object for this. Then you'd select student counts per university (or class or school, whatever your object is):

```
select u.get_student_count() from university u;
```

Comment: `A student has no count you can retrieve` A table of Object is created and populated as well. Its not shown in the example. So when you say table has no count what do you actaully mean to say ?

Comment: @XING: A record in the students table is a student. A student has no record count. A student may have a count of classes, subjects, books, pencils, whatever. But the OP is interested in the number of students. The number of students of what? Of the students in a school or university or something along those lines obviously. So to make the object idea work, we need a university table for instance. Each record represents a university and this may have a method to count the students. (The method would take the university ID of the record and count students in the student table matching that ID.)

Comment: `A record in the students table is a student` - and whats wrong in having a count of records in the `Student` table. Why do you think having a count of records in `Student` table is not going to work. I mean i dont know what OP need is what wrong in only getting the count. Why you want to collaborate it as an attribute. I know you are think from OOPs point of view but wanted to understand if there is an issue in doing what OP asked

Comment: @XING: Either you use objetcs (a university having students and a method to tell you how many) or you don't. If you don't, then `select count(*) from students` or `select count(*) from students where university_id = 1`. If you do, then `select u.get_student_count() from university u`, not `select s.get_student_count() from student s`.